# Using reflection to find custom attribute declarations in all assemblies

Tags: unity, code-reflection

In the Unity documentation section `Overview of .NET in Unity` (https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.1/Documentation/Manual/overview-of-dot-net-in-unity.html), it states:

> Mono and IL2CPP internally cache all C# reflection (System.Reflection)
> objects and by design, Unity doesn’t garbage collect them.

and

> To minimize the garbage collector overhead, avoid methods such as
> Assembly.GetTypes and Type.GetMethods() in your application, which
> create a lot of C# reflection objects at runtime. Instead, you should
> scan assemblies in the Editor for the required data and serialize
> and/or codegen it for use at runtime.

For a library that I am creating, I need to be able to find all of the custom attribute declarations (which are placed on methods) and for that I am using the following code snippet:

```
foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
{
    foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
        foreach (var method in type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            // Check if method has attribute and if so, process that method.
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like I am breaking both suggestions made by Unity themselves (`avoid methods such as Assembly.GetTypes and Type.GetMethods()`), but I just don't know how to do it another way.

I do this logic only once at start and save the results and I don't want all of that assembly and type data to be in memory and put pressure on the GC. I want all that assembly and type data to be collected after I have finished finding all of the methods with attributes and that's it.

Also, I don't really understand what Unity means with `Instead, you should scan assemblies in the Editor for the required data and serialize and/or codegen it for use at runtime.`

Can someone please help me get this right (the most efficient way) since performance is very important for the library I am creating?

EDIT:
I am creating a networking library and implemented the feature of remote procedure calls (RPCs). Basically, user can tag any of their methods with `[ClientRpc]` or `[ServerRpc]` attributes and my library is going to find all of them when starting the game. Those tags are needed to make RPC sending more efficient by hashing methods and also enforces cleaner code when using the library.

Comment: It's hard for us to suggest alternative ways to implement your feature, because you have not told us what your feature *is*. To know whether it's doing a job that can be offloaded to edit time / compile time via codegen or serialization, we need to know details about the job it's doing when it processes these methods after it has found them via reflection. Try editing your question to give us a more complete view of what you need to achieve.

Comment: The problem is finding the methods themselves, not the feature that I am implementing using found methods. Feature already works, but I am concerned that using the code snippet provided above will allocate a bunch of reflection objects which are not going to get collected and make subsequent garbage collection calls much slower (since there are a bunch of reflection objects just sitting in memory doing nothing).

Comment: We know the problem is finding the methods *at runtime*. To see if we can avoid doing it at runtime — by doing it at edit time and serializing the results to data we can read without doing the massive reflection search, or by generating equivalent direct code at compile time to bypass runtime reflection — we need to know what you are doing with these methods. That will tell us what kind of data we could serialize to support that use, or what kind of code we'd need to generate at compile time. Or, it will tell us whether those options are not available for this use case, and we need other ways.

Comment: I have edited my question and added explanation of what I am using attributes for.